# how do you only allow uppercase or lowercase in inputs?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm already using `elif not re.match("^[a-z]*$", first_name)`, but every time I enter a capital letter for the name, it returns the message I use if they are using anything other than a letter in the alphabet. Thank You in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Just a check, can't you simplify this approach by lowering the case of the word? Or by making it go upper? Maybe it's a more simple solution

Comment: Could you share the code in question?

Comment: If you want to use both uppercase and lowercase, you should change the regex to `re.match("^[a-zA-Z]*$", first_name)`

Comment: to check if the first char of a string `s` is uppercase, just use `s[0].isupper()`.

Comment: Thank you @pecey that helped a lot. I will check to see if I can use everyone else's suggestions to help simplify the code I already have.

Answer (score 0):

For lower case:

```py
s1 = input().lower()
```

and for upper case:

```py
s1 = input().upper()
```

This should just work fine. All it is doing is converting the input to either `upper` or `lower` case as specified.
Hope this helps :)